# cv2.boundingRect rect format documentation

Tags: python, opencv

Why this code produce `(1, 1, 1, 1)` result, as I understand `cv2.boundingRect` return rect in format `x,y,w,h`, but why `w,h` is not zero in this case?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cv2.__version__
'4.4.0'

np.__version__
'1.19.2'

a = np.ones((8,2))
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(a.astype(np.float32))
```

There is no much information in the bindings docs:

```
def boundingRect(array): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """
    boundingRect(array) -> retval
    .   @brief Calculates the up-right bounding rectangle of a point set or non-zero pixels of gray-scale image.
    .   
    .   The function calculates and returns the minimal up-right bounding rectangle for the specified point set or
    .   non-zero pixels of gray-scale image.
    .   
    .   @param array Input gray-scale image or 2D point set, stored in std::vector or Mat.
    """
    pass
```

**Update:**

Seems in C++ it returned like `return Rect(xmin, ymin, xmax - xmin + 1, ymax - ymin + 1);`

Answer (score 2):

Not in the correct format. One way is to compute the points in Python/OpenCV.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((8,2))
points = np.column_stack(np.where(a.transpose() > 0))

x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(points)
print(x,y,w,h)
```

Returns:

```
0 0 2 8
```

Comment: `np.ones((8,2))` supposed to be 8 points already.

Comment: Each point has (x, y) coordinates, so `np.ones((8,2))` is 8 points with 2 dimensions.

Comment: It is 8x2 with default dtype=np.float64. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html

Comment: There is a type conversion on second line `a.astype(np.float32)`